# krakend spring security. Basic endpoint authentication won't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, api-gateway, krakend

My SecurityAdapter:

```
@Override
   public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
   {
      var authManager = auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
      for (var user : userConfiguration.getUsers()) {
         authManager.withUser(user.getName())
                    .password("{noop}" + user.getPassword())
                    .roles(user.getRole());
      }
   }

@Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
   {
      // @formatter:off
      httpSecurity
               .csrf()
               .disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
               .httpBasic()
               .and()
               .exceptionHandling()
               .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
      // @formatter:on
   }
```

in application.yml i have this security config;

```
security:
  users:
    - name: someUser
      password: somepwd
      role: someAdmin
    - name: ...
```

my krakend.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://www.krakend.io/schema/v3.json",
  "version": 3,
  "port": 9000,
  "timeout": "300000s",
  "cache_ttl": "4000s",
  "extra_config": {
    "router": {
      "return_error_msg": true
    }
  },
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "@comment": "Feature: POST boards with basic authentification",
      "endpoint": "/apps",
      "output_encoding": "no-op",
      "method": "POST",
      "backend": [
        {
          "host": [
            "http://ipaddress:4603"
          ],
          "method": "POST",
          "url_pattern": "/apps",
          "extra_config": {
            "modifier/martian": {
              "body.Modifier": {
                "scope": [
                  "request"
                ],
                "@comment": "Send a {'msg':'you rock!'}",
                "body": "Ym9hcm......"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
...
```

i got a:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 401,
            "title": "UNAUTHORIZED",
            "detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource. Missing Authorization Key im Header."
        }
    ]
}
```

but when i called the api directly with the encryption in `base64` it works. In apigateway with krakend, according to the docu https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/authentication/basic-authentication/
i have to use `bcrypt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but:

1. If you want that KrakenD passes the authentication to your spring backend, then you should use a [Header modifier](https://www.krakend.io/docs/backends/martian/#header-modifier)
2. If you want KrakenD to prevent the usage of endpoints without passing user and password, then the `auth/basic` component is correct. This is an enterprise functionality (as it shows in the URL), so not sure why you ask in Stack overflow rather than using their support if you are already paying for this.